# updateing gcc4.0.1 to gcc4.2.1 on mac OS 10.5.7

Tags: macos, gcc

I would like to my gcc compiler.

I am running mac OS 10.5.7.

I downloaded Xcode3.0 which has gcc4.0.1 and that seems to work fine. But now the program I need to install seems to require gcc4.2.1. Is there are simple way to upgrade/install?

I downloaded the gcc4.2.1 but came across a myriad of other programs that I would have to install to compile gcc4.2.1  (http://gcc.gnu.org/install/prerequisites.html). I can't seem to find a lot of them on my computer eg. ISO C++98 compiler.

I'd be very grateful if anyone has any advice on how best to proceed?

Thank you in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Xcode 3.1 brings gcc 4.2 and supports 10.5, so get that instead. I believe the latest version is 3.1.4.